# How to pip install tensorflow on El Capitan?

Tags: python, tensorflow, osx-elcapitan

It appears that El Capitan's system integrity protection is preventing me from following the instructions for getting Tensorflow running on OSX.

I've followed [the installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) but the final install step fails:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

fails with:

```
Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
...
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

I've managed to get past that by ignoring the installation of six:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL --ignore-installed six
```

But now testing my installation does not work:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
....
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get it working by using easy_install to upgrade numpy. This seems like a nasty mess so I'd love to either hear a better solution, or have someone explain to me why this is fine.

The command, for those playing along:

```
sudo easy_install numpy
```

Comment: I had the same issue using numpy with CV2. The error suggests version 10 (0xa) is required, so I tried  pip install "numpy==1.10.1" with no luck. Finally, easy_install worked! Would be great to know why.

Comment: Specifying the upgrade with `sudo easy_install --upgrade numpy` worked for me.